# why does Nhibernate query all over a Collection to remove a child?

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

Hello
These are the classes :

```
 public class Child
 {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Name { get; set; }
 }

 public class Parent
 {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
 }
```

when I want to remove a child from collection, I'd write something like :

```
currentParent.Children.Remove(toBeDeletedChild);
```

the problem is when the line above wants to be executed, I get numerous queries to database.
It seems if it works as a loop which querys all over the children and looking for
the child like this Pseudo:

```
foreach(child in currentParent.Children)
   if(child==toBeDeletedChild)
      delete(child);
```

It means I'll get 100 queries to database for deleting a child from a parent with 100 children.

I'm using **NH3** and **Fluent Nhibernate**

Mapping of Parent Class:

```
HasMany(p => p.Children)
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Comment: Hmmm, I've put the Mapping above. Can mapping cause the problem?!?!?! :-)

Comment: It should fetch all Children in a single request when hitting the Children-collection, so something is obviously off. Do you have 2nd-level cache enabled?

Comment: nope, it's off...anyway, why it doesn't create a simple delete query?! it's more rational to do that!!!

Comment: Eager fetch the collection in the fetch query or specify it as an aggregate for the query.  It wont have to load each row then.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the **Parent** to

```
public class Parent
 {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
 }
```

and in the **ParentMap**

```
HasMany(p => p.Children).AsSet()
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Also you would need to use `HashSet` instead of list for the children collection.